# Image not rendering on page the way I would like it to using Vue

Tags: image, vue.js

I have been working on a project and this but is driving me crazy. I can not get the appropriate image to show up on my page.  I have 4 users each from a different country and trying to display their home country on a map.

```
 import canada from "@/assets/country/canada.png"
 import england from "@/assets/country/england.png"
 import usa from "@/assets/country/usa.png"
 import belgium from "@/assets/country/belgium.png"

  if(data.geolocation){
        let countryMarker = data.country
       
        // let canada = require("@/assets/country/canada.png")
        // let england =  require("@/assets/country/england.png")
        // let usa  =  require("@/assets/country/usa.png")
        // let belgium =  require("@/assets/country/belgium.png")
      
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {
            lat: data.geolocation.lat,
            lng: data.geolocation.lng
          },
          map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          icon: usa,         
          title: data.alias
          
       })
```

when I console log countryMarker i get the correct country, or data.country for that matter.  But when I make icon: countryMarker it does not work with the image i want of each countries flag.  But as above if I put usa in for icon: all the markers are showing up with the American flag. So that tells me it is reading something right???
or else no flag would show up?? Likewise when I use the other countries as a non variable. All the other attributes are correct.  I just can't get the image to match with the appropriate icon I want

Comment: What's the value of `data.country`?

Comment: it is the actual country name.  usa, canada....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're trying to lookup the image resource that corresponds to the country name in the `data.country` string. To do that, you could create a lookup table/object (1️⃣), and then reference it when creating `google.maps.Marker` (2️⃣):

```js
import canada from "@/assets/country/canada.png"
import england from "@/assets/country/england.png"
import usa from "@/assets/country/usa.png"
import belgium from "@/assets/country/belgium.png"

// 1️⃣
const flags = {
  canada,
  england,
  usa,
  belgium
}

if (data.geolocation) {
  let countryMarker = data.country

  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //...
    icon: flags[countryMarker] // 2️⃣
  })
}
```

Comment: tony19 you are a god send!!!  I have spent two days running around with different ideas on how to get it to work.  I would love ya like a brother.....but I am afraid Blue Jays are the superior team!  Many thanks all the same.